# JQPlot define x-axes as days, y-axes as views - way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

So this is code where I want to define x-axes with value of views, and y-axes as value of
day, or tick. I have small knowledge with jqplot or javascript, so could you please give me examples of how I could draw such chart using this. PHP variable $daynumber is usually 1 (for one day, one row) but I can give date aswell, which variant could be better?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var line1 = [<?php echo ''.$views.','; ?>];
    var ticks = [<?php echo ''.$daynumber.','; ?>];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [line1], {
        legend: {show:false},
        axes:{
            // here I define y-axes.
          xaxis:{
          ticks: ticks,
          tickOptions:{
            angle: -30
          },
          tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            label:'Days',
          labelOptions:{
            fontFamily:'Helvetica',
            fontSize: '11pt'
          },
          labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
          },
            // here I define y-axes
          yaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{
                labelPosition: 'middle',
                angle:-30
            },

            tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,

            labelOptions:{
                fontFamily:'Helvetica',
                fontSize: '11pt'
            },
                label:'Views'
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in [Date axes page for jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php).

It says that your line should look in format

`line1=[ [date,value], [anotherdate,otherValue] ];`

And dont forget to include date plugin for jqplugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqplot/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> ir pievienots fails un headerī šitā rindiņa, bet nerādas, kāpēc Dadz?

Comment: <script class="include" src="js/jqplot/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  </script> bija japievieno...